# How Firestore handle linebreak

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In the old Realtime database console, i can put \n to the value field to mark a line break on a string. On the current Firestore database console, \n will be regarded as normal string.

However, what I noticed when i use iOS or Android app client to set the document to the database, the line break will be preserved although it is not visible in the web console.

Comment: If you think this is not the correct behavior for the console, please file a bug report.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/